# Windows Desktop App - Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports, log4net, visual-studio-2022

I have a Windows Desktop c# application in .Net Framework 4.6.2. This Application is using Crystal Reports (13.0.3500.0) as well.

Everything was working fine, I have just changed my development machine. On the new machine with Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2022, When I open any Form (Which has Crystal Report Viewer), I get the following error.

`Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I have tried all available solutions:

1. Installed both 32-bit and 64-bit Crystal Reports SDK
2. I have removed and re-added log4net from Nuget.
3. I have placed log4net in GAC in both 32bit and 64bit folders.
4. Enabled / Disabled Preferred 32 bit from settings.

I believe the issue is with Public Token 692fbea5521e1304. How can I find log4net with this public token? Even on Nuget or on Apache log4net with this public token is not available.